# save_and_open_page with ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, rspec, qunit, poltergeist

I have a background in developing applications with Ruby on Rails, where I use Capybara and Rspec to render the output of what Poltergeist "sees".

I'm just starting out with Ember and was writing my first acceptance test when I really started to miss that feature. Is there a way to render the html generated at a certain point in the acceptance test with ember-cli? What would I have to do to set it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test('clicking login authenticates', function(){
  visit('/');
  return pauseTest();
  // The test will never proceed to execute this click
  click('a:contains(Login)');
});
```

Try to use *pauseTest()* while running the tests in the web browser:

```
ember test --server
```

The small window in the browser should pause and you can see its state.

P.S. You need Ember 1.9 or higher.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even notice what was happening in that little window.

Comment: UPDATE: you may have to open your browser and navigate to `http://localhost:4200/tests` to see the paused window. Also, in latest versions of ember, `pauseTest()` now needs to be imported from `@ember/test-helpers`